# Uploading multiple files and renaming - PHP

Tags: php, file-rename, multiple-file-upload

I'm uploading multiple files.
Main function works fine, but I have to change the names of uploading files Like:
`name1.jpg`, `name2.jps`, `name3.jpg`, ...

```
$i = 1;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/name'.$i++.'.'.$extension)){
     echo '{"status":"success"}';
     exit;
}
```

Number `$i` should grow with amount of uploaded files.
I hope that explained it correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a **loop**:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

     $name_array = $_FILES['files']['name'];
     $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
     // Number of files
     $count_tmp_name_array = count($tmp_name_array);

     // We define the static final name for uploaded files (in the loop we will add an number to the end)
     $static_final_name = "name";

     for($i = 0; $i < $count_tmp_name_array; $i++){
          // Get extension of current file
          $extension = pathinfo($name_array[$i] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

          // Pay attention to $static_final_name 
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$static_final_name.$i.".".$extension)){
               echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
          } else {
               echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
          }

     }

}
```

Comment: What if I want to use a timestamp instead of            .$static_final_name.$i.?

Comment: @SamuelRamzan You could have problems, since the timestamp change every second and it is possible that several files are uploaded in a single second, so you would find that they would be overwritten

Comment: You could use: `$uniqueFileName = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);`. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594109