# How to upload uniquely named image on php?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

Hi I have got the following code. I am trying to upload an image with a unique name by using the `tempnam` function.

```
$upfile = tempnam('client_images', '');
unlink($upfile);
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upfile);

if($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] != "image/gif" && $_FILES["userfile"]["type"] != "image/pjpeg" && $_FILES["userfile"]["type"] != "image/png" && $_FILES["userfile"]["type"] != "image/jpeg") 
{ 
    echo "ERROR: You may only upload .jpg or .gif or .png files"; 
} 
else 
{ 
     if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],$upfile)) 
     { 
     echo "ERROR: Could Not Move File into Directory"; 
     } 
     else 
     { 
     echo "Temporary File Name: " .$_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]."<br />"; 
     echo "File Name: " .$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]."<br />"; 
     echo "File Size: " .$_FILES["userfile"]["size"]."<br />"; 
     echo "File Type: " .$_FILES["userfile"]["type"]."<br />"; 
     } 
    } 
    ?>
```

However for some reason I cannot see these images in my `client_images` folder.

The output looks like this:

```
Temporary File Name: C:\Windows\Temp\phpA9F3.tmp
File Name: client.png
```

Why is the Temp saving it as a `.tmp` and not a `.png?`
What could I be doing wrong with this?

Comment: You really have a _root_ folder on the server called `/client_images`? I'm guessing not.

Comment: ooooh you're right, but it's still stored as .tmp, how do I save it as jpg?

Comment: I just removed the / and now it saves to the right folder! :) But not as an image file

Comment: `tempnam` create .tmp files. It's by design. It's for generating... temporary filenames.

Comment: There are _so many_ answers on stackoverflow about uploading files with PHP and generating unique filenames. Here's just one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460164/unique-and-temporary-file-names-in-php

Comment: why `unlink($upfile);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $upfile)) {
    //take care of error
}
```

With

```
$nameyouwant = "sample"; //we'll use the extension from the source filename
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
$newfilename = $nameyouwant. '.' . end($temp); //add file extension
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],$upfile . $newfilename)) {
    //take care of error
}
else{
    //save success
}
```